Can anyone explain this key-combo sequence
Using Fedora 27 ( in a vm, not that it matters but if anyone needs to know).
At a bash terminal entered the character '=' and then  ALT =   (simultaneous) produces a file listing exactly as if 'ls' had been entered but also showing the hidden config files. I've checked my alias list and obviously nothing corresponds to this key combo. Any suggestions ?
So just to be clear,  in the terminal there is one '=' displayed and then I entered the ALT= immediately after that.

The initial = does not really matter, it's only needed because completion does not trigger on an empty prompt.
Hitting Alt+= will send the control sequence ^[=. You can figure this out by hitting Ctrl+v in the terminal, followed by your key combination.
By default in bash, this is bound to the Readline function possible-completions:
$ bind -P | grep '='
possible-completions can be found on "\e=", "\e?".

possible-completions is defined in man 1 bash as:

possible-completions (M-?)
List the possible completions of the text before point.


Note that these bindings assume you leave bash readline in 'emacs' mode. If you use 'vi' with 'set -o vi' then these bindings do not take place and results will differ.
